# How to send Image from Vue to Node ( Express ) and store it in AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, vue.js, amazon-s3

I was doing a school managent platform for my local school, everything goes fine except problem that I just witness. From Vue front-end how to send picked image to server , so that my backend could receive it and store it in my s3 bucket.

I do not have problem with storing image, but problem is in correct receiving and get the `path` of the image.

Thank you in advance!

Here is my uploadFile function

```
const uploadFile = (buffer, filename) => {
    const photo_url = "";
    const params = {
        Bucket: 'BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: `student_${filename}`, // File name you want to save as in S3
        Body: buffer,
        ACL: "public-read"
    };

    s3.upload(params, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(`File uploaded at location ${data.Location}`);
        photo_url= data.Location;
    });    

    return photo_url;

};
```

My route `index.js`

```
app.post("/api/signup", upload.single('file'), db.signUpStudent);
```

My REQUEST and RESPONSE :

```
const signUpStudent = (request, response) => {
        const student = request.body;
const buffer = request.file.path;
    var student_photo = uploadFile.uploadFile(buffer, request.file.originalname);
}
```

And then I am inserting the URL of stored image to my SQL table

Comment: The question is missing a code example of the part where the user is experiencing issues. Please edit your question adding a code example and a specific question describing the error you are receiving.

Comment: I did not receive any errors, I cannot construct logic behind that . In order to upload to s3 bucket we should specify path to our file. But in my case path in another computer (Vue frontend) , And the problem is in which way file should be sent to api , so that I will be able to send back to server with valid path ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that s3.upload is an async function, so your photo_url var is not populated yet when you return it, you just have to return it inside the callback.

```
s3.upload(params, function(err, data){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(`File uploaded at location ${data.Location}`);
    photo_url= data.Location;
    return photo_url;
});
```